# Auto rude/NC flags should have some non-link text

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, moderator-tools

Currently, the 'possible comment abuse: too many rude/NC (auto)' is comprised entirely of a link. The link is useful, but it removes the ability to dismiss the flag individually.

Can we make part of the flag be non-linked? Perhaps the timestamps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, didn't think about that (in my testing and general browsing, I use middle-clicks extensively, which don't show this issue).

With you in the next build - existing flags will not change.

Comment: This might belong in another request, but how hard would it be to dismiss other active flags on the user before casting another flag? I'm seeing quite a few duplicates on http://stackoverflow.com/admin/dashboard?flagtype=commenttoomanydeletedrudenotconstructiveauto.

Comment: It should only be raised once a day per user (at most). So, I'd expect some duplication to happen over time for some users. Can you open a new feature request for dismissing all open rude/NC auto flags for a single user?

Comment: Not seeing that behavior - these two were raised within 20 seconds of each other: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39580347/c-console-input-skipping, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334429/remove-invisible-characters-from-a-string

Comment: Yeah, seeing that. Something broken there. Will investigate.